# How to get jquery not Javascript hint for autocompletion in CodeMirror?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I am working on online JS IDE using CodeMirror in php.

in CodeMirror JavaScript autocompletion hint is available.

I want to show Jquery hint on Javascript mode.

It is possible in CodeMirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tern](http://ternjs.net) has both a [CodeMirror plugin](http://codemirror.net/demo/tern.html) and a set of [type definitions](http://ternjs.net/defs/jquery.json) for jQuery. Putting those pieces together should give you the result you want, though some programming is required to integrate the Tern plugin.